# sandbox mode on Google Play?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, admob

I want to do the process of "publishing" my application to Google Play (android market)
my application is not ready yet, but AdMob demanding it for the registration.

so, I don't want to publish my app yet, although I want to combine AdMob in my app
is there a way to register to google play without really publishing your app?
or, using the adMob SDK without registration to Google Play?

Answer (score 3):

The package field for AdMob registration is **optional**.  You can leave that field blank, and fill it in later when you're ready to publish your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your application to Google Play, and there is function Publish, or Unpublish. If you want add but don`t Publish application. When your application will ready, add as other version application.